# /raylight/v1/documents/id/parameters/ does not return all parameters

Tags: business-intelligence, business-objects

I am using this api to get all `prompt` parameters (v4.2 sp3). When the document does not contain any `context` parameters API returns all parameters as expected. However if there is some `context` parameter API returns only `context` parameters...

Example: Document id = 1 does not contain context parameter

`GET /raylight/v1/documents/1/parameters/`

I get something like

```
<parameters>
    <parameter optional="false" type="prompt" dpId="DP0">
        <id>0</id>
        ...
    <parameter>
    <parameter optional="false" type="prompt" dpId="DP0">
        <id>1</id>
        ...
    <parameter>
</parameters>
```

The same Document id = 2 but with context parameter

`GET /raylight/v1/documents/2/parameters/`

I get something like

```
<parameters>
    <parameter optional="false" type="context" dpId="DP0">
        <id>0</id>
        ...
    <parameter>
</parameters>
```

There are no other 2 parameters...
**However they are available directly**

`GET /raylight/v1/documents/2/parameters/1`

returns

```
<parameter optional="false" type="prompt" dpId="DP0">
    <id>1</id>
    ...
<parameter>
```

`GET /raylight/v1/documents/2/parameters/2`

returns

```
<parameter optional="false" type="prompt" dpId="DP0">
    <id>2</id>
    ...
<parameter>
```

`GET /raylight/v1/documents/2/parameters/3` returns http 404.

**How can I get all parameters or at least parameters' count?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is a `Context`, it is not possible to have the full list of parameters. You first need to reply to the `Context parameters`, so that **Web Intelligence** is able to build the list of standard prompts.

In fact `Prompts` depends on the `Context(s)`, this is the reason why you need to disambiguate them before obtaining a complete list of parameters.